# How can ndk-build be run without re-compiling files?

Tags: android, ndk-build

When compiling with `ndk-build`, I got the error that the argument list was too long. To solve this I want to split the library in a few smaller libraries. As I already have the object files, and it took several hours to compile them, I was looking for a way to preserve the object files I got from my earlier compilation. Is it possible to preserve those files with `ndk-build` and how so?

Answer (score 0):

once you build `ndk` your .so the file will be generated in lib folder copy that file and paste it in `lib` folder of your app use it as a library

when you run app you can find it in `device File Explorer` -> data -> data -> your package Name -> lib

load this lib(.so) file in `static` block where you want use it like this...

```
 static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("yourLibName");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: No library was build, because of an error when making the library. I already have the obj files just not the library itself.